# How to append to an Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an application that is using  [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.aspx).
This application should add data to an excel file each time , So where should i tell the app to start from ? how can i get the first empty cell to start adding to ?

```
Excel.Application app;
Excel.Workbook Wbook;
Excel._Worksheet ws_1;
Excel._Worksheet ws_2;
Excel._Worksheet ws_3;

app = new Excel.Application();
Wbook = app.Workbooks.Add();
app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\tst.xlsx");

ws_1 = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
ws_2 = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
ws_3 = (Excel._Worksheet)app.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Will return the row number of the last cell even when only a single cell in the last row has data.

You can also use [SpecialCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213567%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and avoid looping over data:

```
Range rng = new Range();
rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a range and check cell values:

```
int row, column;
Range allCells = ws_1.Cells.get_Range("A1", "Z1");
foreach (Range c in allCells)
{ 
   string temp = c.Formula as string;
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp)) 
   {
      row = c.Row;
      column = c.Column;
      break;
   }
}
```

Then `row` and `column` is  row and column index of your first `empty cell`.